# printf in bash: "09" and "08" are invalid numbers, "07" and "06" are fine

Tags: bash, shell, printf

This is my bash script - I just want to left-pad a set of numbers with zeroes:

```
printf "%04d" "09"
printf "%04d" "08"
printf "%04d" "07"
printf "%04d" "06"
```

Output:

```
./rename.sh: line 3: printf: 09: invalid number 
0000
./rename.sh: line 4: printf: 08: invalid number 
0000 
0007
0006
```

What...?

Only 09 and 08 are causing the problem: every other number in my sequence seems to be OK.

Comment: Because preceding integer  by `0` mean *octal representation*. Try: `printf %d\\n 070` and/or `printf %d\\n 010`

Comment: Wow, I thought I was loosing it, couldn't figure out why this happens just for the 8 & 9 figures. thanks!

Answer (score 46, accepted):

If you have your `"09"` in a variable, you can do

```
a="09"
echo "$a"
echo "${a#0}"
printf "%04d" "${a#0}"
```

Why does this help? Well, a number literal starting with `0` but having no `x` at the 2nd place is interpreted as octal value.

Octal value only have the digits `0`..`7`, `8` and `9` are unknown.

`"${a#0}"` strips one leading `0`. The resulting value can be fed to `printf` then, which prints it appropriately, with `0` prefixed, in 4 digits.

If you have to expect that you get values such as `"009"`, things get more complicated as you'll have to use a loop which eliminates all excess `0`s at the start, or an `extglob` expression as mentioned in the comments.

Comment: Why on earth "-1" without any further notice what was wrong?!

Comment: you want `${a##0}` in case you get something like "009"

Comment: That does not help at all - `a="009"; echo ${a##0}` yields 09. I would have to use a loop here - but the OP only wroute about `08`, `09` and not `008`, `009`. Alas, this `#`/`##` stuff does not work with regexes - in regex, one could write `s/^0*//g`.

Comment: Ah yes, right. This can be written: `shopt -s extglob; echo ${a##+(0)}`

Comment: +1 from me, because your solution did help a lot, but I do have slight doubts that unexplained bash variable substitutions have any educational value for readers who dig this up in the future. To clarify, the OP's error comes from the fact that printf interprets numbers starting with 0 as octal, which does work fine from 00-07. Hence the suggestion to strip leading zeroes before handing the number to printf.

Comment: @unixtippse You are right, thus I added some explanation now.

Comment: Rather than trying to use the shell to parse the string, it might be cleaner to do something like `$(expr $a)`

Answer (score 31):

Bash's numeric arithmetic evaluation syntax `(( ... ))` can convert to base 10 (therefor ensuring correct interpretation) with the following syntax: `(( 10#$var ))`. Or, in the case of a raw number: `(( 10#08 ))`. Very simple & clean and can be used anywhere you're sure the base should be 10, but can't guarantee a leading zero won't be included.

So, in your example it would be as follows:

```
printf "%04d\n" $(( 10#09 ))
printf "%04d\n" $(( 10#08 ))
printf "%04d\n" $(( 10#07 ))
printf "%04d\n" $(( 10#06 ))
```

Producing the following output:

```
0009
0008
0007
0006
```

With this syntax, since you're then working with the value of the variable instead of variable itself, incrementors `(( var++ ))` & decrementors `(( var-- ))` won't work, but can still be relatively cleanly implemented as `var=$(( 10#var + 1 ))` and `var=$(( 10#var - 1 ))`, respectively.

I first encountered this solution [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1402291#post8805742), but [this answer to a similar Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/879010/146716) also demonstrates it.

Comment: Note that this works in bash but not in dash (default ubuntu shell). In dash, the following error appears: "arithmetic expression: expecting EOF"

Answer (score 20):

Numbers beginning with "0" are treated as octal (i.e. base-8).  Therefore, "8" and "9" aren't valid digits.

See http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Arithmetic.

This behaviour is inherited from languages like C.

Comment: Thanks. Any idea how I can left-pad these numbers with zeroes? Do I need to strip the leading zero first, then left-pad - if so, how?

Comment: Just remove the "0"s from the argument.  printf will do the left-padding for you, based on that format string.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I remove the leading zeroes? I can't use `printf "%d" "08"` for the same reason! (the example above is a massive simplification of what I need to do - in fact the argument is a parameter, so I can't edit it by hand each time, I need a programmatic way to strip leading zeroes before adding them...)

Comment: Oli means you need to remove the leading 0 from the number, not the format. i.e. - printf %04d 9, not 09.

Comment: @Richard: Oh, I see.  Do you mean that the "08" comes from somewhere out of your control, and you want to treat it as if it were "8"?

Comment: See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8078167/bizarre-issue-with-printf-in-bash-script09-and-08-are-invalid-numbers-07/11804275#answer-11804275) for the specifics, but numbers can be converted to base 10 with the following syntax: `(( 10#$var ))`. Pretty clean & easy.

Answer (score 9):

Floating point is handled differently:

```
printf "%04.f" "009"
```

This gives the correct output, without dealing with any fancy bashisms (per @Oli Charlesworth's answer, 0*** is treated as octal, but I believe that Bash ignores octal/hex identifiers for floating-point numbers)

Comment: Thanks! This works great with output of `date` as in `printf "%.0f\n" $(date +%m)` returned `9` instead of that pesky `09` --and no octal mess.

Comment: Very helpful, I was using `ACCOUNT_ID=$(printf "%012d" $ACCOUNT_ID)` to zero fill AWS account IDs... but failed when people properly included leading zeros with the error  `-bash: printf: 012345678901: invalid octal number` ... but using your solution `printf "%012.f" $ACCOUNT_ID` works great!

Answer (score 4):

Just to add to [Oli's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8078167/bizarre-issue-with-printf-in-bash-script09-and-08-are-invalid-numbers-07/8078183#8078183), in order to pad a number with zeroes it is enough to put a `0` after the `%`, as you did:

`printf "%04d" "9"`

Answer (score 3):

### Why did “09” and “08” are invalid numbers, “07” and “06” are fine

Because preceding integer by `0` is a conventional shortcut meaning ***number is octal***.

```
printf "%d\n" 010 0100
8
64

printf "%o\n" 8 64 0100
10
100
100
printf "%04o\n" 8 64 0100
0010
0100
0100
```

### How to work with this?

#### Using bash integer: preceding number by `10#`

Under bash, you could precise by this way, which *base* is used for number

```
echo $(( 10#0100))
100
echo $(( 10#0900))
900
echo $(( 10#0900 ))
900
```

and

```
echo $(( 8#100 ))
64
echo $(( 2#100 ))
4
```

Of course!

> There are only 10 types of people in the world: those who understand binary, and those who don't.

#### Using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) ***Parameter Expansion***

For this, you have to use a variable

```
a=09
echo ${a#0}
9
```

This will work fine until you just have only one `0` to drop.

```
a=0000090

echo ${a#*0}
000090
echo ${a##0}
000090
```

For this, you coul use *`extglob`* feature:

```
echo ${a##*(0)}
0000090
shopt -s extglob
echo ${a##*(0)}
90
```

#### Using *`floating point`* with `printf`

```
printf "%.0f\n" 09
9
```

I like using `-v` option of `printf` for setting some variable:

```
printf -v a %.0f 09
echo $a
9
```

or even if

```
a=00090
printf -v a %.0f $a
echo $a
90
```

Comment: Further joke: [Why did my alphabet had 40 letters? Or why dropping STDERR is not always a good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14423442/1765658)

Answer (score 2):

Adding `*` makes shell parameter expansion matching greedy (see, for example, [Shell Tipps: use internal string handling](http://www.tramm.li/iWiki/ShellTipps.html))!

```
# strip leading 0s
- a="009"; echo ${a##0}
+ a="009"; echo ${a##*0}
```

Comment: This doesn't work correctly. Try: `a="00000092323005"; echo ${a##*0}`.

Comment: ... or `a=000000090; echo ${a##*0}; echo ${a##0}`. will return ` ` (nothing) and `00000000090`

Answer (score 1):

Much simpler to convert from octal to decimal:

```
nm=$((10#$nm))
```

Answer (score 1):

if `a=079`
first, remove the trailing zeros by

```
a=`echo $a | sed 's/^0*//'`
```

then do the zero-padding

```
printf "%04d" $a
```