# Why does my alphabet have 40 letters? Or why dropping STDERR is not always a good idea?

Tags: bash, error-handling

### `for ((i=000;i<040;i++));do ...`

From 0 to 39, there is 40 values!? ... for printing from  `A` to `Z`???

```bash
for ((i=000;i<040;i++));do
    printf %b "$(printf \\%03o\  $((65+0$i)))"
  done 2>/dev/null |
  xargs
```

```
A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
```

strange!?

There is **85** values, from 70 to 154:

```bash
for ((i=0070;i<0155;i++));do
    printf %b "$(printf \\%03o\  $((19+0$i)))"
  done 2>/dev/null |
    xargs
```

```
A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
```

> ##### Dummy request (about *error handling*)! Don't re-open this!! ;-p

## Answer

> As this question was closed, no answer could be added, so there is **my** explanation:

#### The missunderstanding is done by the (ab)use of **`2>/dev/null`**!!

So, simply dropping this will output:

```bash
for ((i=000;i<040;i++));do
    echo -e $(eval "printf "\\\\%04o" $((65+0$i)) ")
done  |   xargs
```

```
bash: 65+08: value too great for base (error token is "08")
bash: 65+09: value too great for base (error token is "09")
bash: 65+018: value too great for base (error token is "018")
bash: 65+019: value too great for base (error token is "019")
bash: 65+028: value too great for base (error token is "028")
bash: 65+029: value too great for base (error token is "029")
A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
```

Things become more clear!!

We could count *error lines* by using `wc -l`:

```bash
for ((i=000;i<040;i++));do
    echo -e $(eval "printf "\\\\%04o" $((65+0$i)) ")
done 2> >(wc -l >&2) |   xargs
```

```
6
A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
```

There are 6 error lines, because of illegal digit `8` or `9` in octal numbers.

So if this is *octal*, then you could either

```bash
printf %d\\n 040
```

or

```bash
echo $(( 040 ))
```

or

```bash
echo $(( 8#40 ))
```

to convert `040` octal to `32` decimal (`4 * 8 + 0 = 32`).

Then having `32` operation with `6` errors dropped, there are finally 26 outputs.

With `wc -l` again:

```bash
for ((i=0070;i<0155;i++));do
    echo -e $(eval "printf "\\\\%04o" $((19+0$i)) ")
  done 2> >(wc -l >&2) | xargs
```

```
27
A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
```

There are in fact 27 errors, with values from...

```bash
printf "%d\n" 0070 0155
```

```
56
109
```

From 56 to 108! There is not 85 values, but 53!!

```bash
echo $(( 155 - 70 ))  $(( 0155 - 070 ))  $(( 109 - 56 ))
```

```
85 53 53
```

Again: 53 operations with 27 errors = 26 outputs

```bash
echo $((53-27))
```

```
26
```

Yes!

This is the right number of letters (in the alphabet I know)!

### Conclusion

The question could be rewritten as:

> #### *How **abuse of `/dev/null`** could make strange behaviours*

So be carefull when redirecting *`STDERR`*! Avoid simply redirecting *`STDERR`* to `/dev/null`:

```bash
command 2>/dev/null
```

And prefer to use commands like:

```bash
command 2> >(grep -v "unwanted message" >&2)
```

Comment: There are 40 steps. Not 41.

Comment: Hi, @F.Hauri 0-39, including 0;  40 is not there, buddy. i<040 right?

Comment: @Kent Right, `<` is not `<=` but read carefully: There is in fact `0` to ... `037` only ;-)

Comment: @F.Hauri So if you know that, why do you ask the question?

Comment: @Macmade read the original post, edited after 2 mins, (I did'nt understand why). As I think answering this question could make learn a lot about some *strange* behaviours.

Comment: @F.Hauri Next time write a blog post. I'm voting to close this as not a real question, as you obviously posted it while knowing the answer.

Comment: @Macmade I'm sorry, I really think this could add something... What did you call *blog post* does this feature exist on SO?

Comment: @F.Hauri You're just taking valuable time from people here. People could have spent that time answering **real** questions from other users. Get yourself a blog if you want to share your joy of discovering that kind of programming stuff.

Comment: @F.Hauri Ok, removed my down-vote for the effort of maintaining your post and trying to add context... : )

Comment: @Macmade Thanks, the original meaning of this was about `/dev/null` abuse... I think, this is strongly linked to a lot of question about redirections, `STDERR` / `STDIN` and may concern beginers: ( First step in debugging: remove `/dev/null` ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are simply using [octal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) numbers, as your numbers are prefixed by 0.

So it's base 8, not base 10.

Answer (score 6):

You have 31 steps because 040 is [octal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) for decimal 32.

Octal is a numeral system with the base 8. Decimal has the base 10 and hexadecimal 16.

Comment: This is not true. I mean the 1st sentence.

Comment: You may try `for ((i=000;i<=040;i++));do`.

Comment: +1 ah... bash! I was under zsh......!

Comment: At all, 31 step for my alphabet is too much! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use the following to print the alphabet?

```
for letter in {A..Z} ; do
    echo $letter
done
```