# Remove leading zero from BASH array variables

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I am trying to remove leading zeroes from a BASH array... I have an array like:

```
echo "${DATES[@]}"
```

returns

```
01 02 02 03 04 07 08 09 10 11 13 14 15 16 17 18 20 21 22 23
```

I'd like to remove the leading zeroes from the dates and store back into array or another array, so i can iterate in another step... Any suggestions?

I tried this,

```
for i in "${!DATES[@]}"
do
    DATESLZ["$i"]=(echo "{DATES["$i"]}"| sed 's/0*//' ) 
done
```

but failed (sorry, i'm an old Java programmer who was tasked to do some BASH scripts)

Comment: What about just `printf "%d" $DATES` for each item?

Comment: @fedorqui, this is why: `printf "%d" 08` ==> `bash: printf: 08: invalid octal number`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use parameter expansion:

```
DATES=( ${DATES[@]#0} )
```

Comment: You can use [`shopt -s extglob; DATES=("${DATES[@]##+(0)}")`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8078167/bizarre-issue-with-printf-in-bash-script09-and-08-are-invalid-numbers-07#comment9903141_8078505) to remove any number of zeros.

Comment: Be careful when using @l0b0 suggestion. This will remove not only padded 0's but also the value "0" by itself as well. My script required supporting "0". Therefore I needed to build in more logic to recognize if "0" existed before using the `shopt` command, then re-adding "0" to my array at the end after all grooming was complete.

Answer (score 4):

With bash arithmetic, you can avoid the octal woes by specifying your numbers are base-10:

```
day=08
((day++))           # bash: ((: 08: value too great for base (error token is "08")
((day = 10#$day + 1))
echo $day              # 9
printf "%02d\n" $day   # 09
```

Comment: +1 for `10#$day`, but how would you apply it to the current issue?

Comment: Well, the question says "remove the leading zeroes...so i can iterate in another step". There's no need to remove the zeros in the first place.

Comment: I mean OP specifically asked about an *array*.

Comment: I know, but sometimes we shouldn't give people exactly what they ask for ([xy problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem))

Answer (score 1):

You can use bash parameter expansion (see http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) like this:

```
echo ${DATESLZ[@]#0}
```

Answer (score 0):

If: `${onedate%%[!0]*}` will select all 0's in front of the string `$onedate`.

we could remove those zeros by doing this (it is portable):

```
echo "${onedate#"${onedate%%[!0]*}"}"
```

For your case (only bash):

```
#!/bin/bash
dates=( 01 02 02 08 10 18 20 21 0008 00101 )

for onedate in "${dates[@]}"; do
    echo -ne "${onedate}\t"
    echo "${onedate#"${onedate%%[!0]*}"}"
done
```

Will print:

```
$ script.sh
01      1
02      2
02      2
08      8
10      10
18      18
20      20
21      21
0008    8
00101   101
```