# correct pattern to change array values in bash

Tags: arrays, regex, bash, replace

I need to strip the first `0` from all values in an array, e.g. change

```
array=( 01 02 03 [...] 10 [...] 20 [...] )
```

to

```
array=(1 2 3 [...] 10 [...] 20 [...] )
```

I think I can do this with `${parameter/pattern/string}` but I am quite lost with the syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that it's an array of numbers, I'd do it *arithmetically* instead of attempting to perform string replacement:

```
$ a=( {01..20} )
$ echo "${a[@]}"
01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
$ b=()
$ for i in "${a[@]}"; do b+=( $((10#$i)) ); done
$ echo "${b[@]}"
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

Here `$((10#$i))` would cause the variable `i` to be evaluated as a base-10 number.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ array=(01 02 03 10 20)
$ echo "${array[@]#0}"
1 2 3 10 20
```

Answer (score 2):

```
shopt -s extglob
b=("${a[@]##+(0)}")
printf "%s\n" "${b[@]}"
```

Comment: This will strip all leading zeroes, OP asked only for the first in which case `extglob` is not needed. Though @devnull's solution is probably the sanest.

Answer (score -1):

You can use parameter expansion and redefine the array directly:

```
array=(${array[@]#0})
```

`${string#substring}` strips the shortest match of `$substring` from front of `$string`.

If you want to strip multiple zeroes, e.g. `(001 002)` to `(1 2)`, you can use `shopt -s extglob` and then `"${var##*(0)}"`.

#### Test

```
$ a=(01 02 03 10 11)
$ ar=(${a[@]#0})
$ for i in "${ar[@]}"; do echo $i; done
1
2
3
10
11
```

And with multiple zeroes:

```
$ a=(01 11 0003)
$ ar=(${a[@]#0})
$ for i in "${ar[@]}"; do echo ${i##*(0)}; done
1
11
003
$ shopt -s extglob
$ for i in "${ar[@]}"; do echo ${i##*(0)}; done
1
11
3
```

#### Sources:

- [How to change values of bash array elements without loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12744170/1983854).
- [Remove leading zero from BASH array variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16940218/1983854).
- [Bash Shell: Remove (Trim) White Spaces From String / Variable](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-remove-whitespace-from-string/).

Comment: reposted, since the original in http://stackoverflow.com/a/26338759/ was deleted due to somebody who posted the exact same question.